# How can I grab the (text) value instead of the number on a multiple choice field?

Tags: django, forms, view

I have a CreateView class and I'm trying to use the input from a multiple choice field it has as part of the success_url.

It works on my TopicCreateView class because the input is a charfield, but when I try to get it to work on PostCreateView it returns a KeyError. From what i understand it's because it returns the value of the multiple choice field(1, 2, 3 etc) instead of the text between the option tags.

The Topic part works fine.

views.py

```py
class TopicCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Topic
    template_name = 'topic_form.html'
    fields = ['board', 'title']
    success_url = '/topic/{title}'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And here is the models.py

```py
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, default='ETC', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is what I can't get to work, the Post.
views.py

```py
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_form.html'
    fields = ['topic', 'content']
    success_url = '/topic/{topic}'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and models.py

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Unknown', blank=True, null=True)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, default=content, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic
```

Also, the form is the same for both of them:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create A New Post</legend>
                {{ form | crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

So, when I redirect to the newly created topic/thread it works, but I can't do the same for new posts.

Comment: I could see nothing related to multiple choice field in your code snippet... Am I missing something?

Comment: I added the form now, too. Django creates it automatically according to the model with the fields as specified in the model, and since the Post's topic field is a ForeignKey, it translates to a multiple choice field in the html looking like "<option value=1>Topic name here</option>"